# Why packages installed with pip install --user option are not 'visible' from shell?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, package

When I install e.g. [conan.io](https://conan.io/) with pip like so

```
sudo pip install conan
```

after the installation passes (and installs the packages to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`) I can easily trigger command from the installed package (here `conan`) and my shell will find it but when I install it in **user** model like so:

```
pip install --user conan
```

it will install it to `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and my shell will not find it.

What am I doing wrong here or what am I missing?

Comment: I'd start by checking that you don't have multiple python versions and that the pip command corresponds to the correct python version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shell scripts are installed in `~/.local/bin`, you have to add the directory to your `$PATH`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH; conan
```

should work.

Comment: That was it :) thanks. BTW: I had `~/.local/bin` in my path. It seems that I needed to change it to `$HOME/.local/bin` as you suggested to make it work.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why, but tilde doesn't get expanded in PATH